# Create a popup and get results when the user tries to leave my webpage

Tags: javascript, html, confirm

I am trying to use a confirm method for external links.  When you press the link, the question is supposed to popup, asking you if you want to leave the site? Everything goes as planned, except that you leave the site regardless of which button you click.

```
function warning(){
  var warning = document.getElementsByClassName("external");
  warning.onclick = confirm('Do you want to leave');

  if(warning){
    alert("Leaving site");

  }
  else{
    return false;
    alert("Staying on site");
  }
}
```

The above clearly won't work, how do you do it?

Comment: Are your buttons/links setup to execute this code or are you expecting it to function as a catch all? Can you show some markup to see how `warning()` is being used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
warning.onclick = confirm('Do you want to leave');
```

This calls `confirm()` **immediately**, and assigns the result (either true or false) to `onclick` (which is meaningless).

Instead, you need to create an anonymous function that calls `confirm()` and returns the result.

Answer (score 1):

> The above clearly won't work

Yes. There are countless errors in the code:

- Your variable `warning` has the same name as the function - bad practise as this leads to confusion
- `warning.onclick` won't work since `getElementsByClassName` returns a NodeList, and you can attach listeners only to single elements
- `= confirm('Do you want to leave');` directly assigns the result of calling `confirm`. You certainly wanted to assign a function that, it will get invoked when the event happens
- `if(warning)` will always be true since even an empty NodeList is truthy
- `return false; alert()` - the alert will never be executed. A `return` statement immediately jumps out of the function.

> how do you do it?

Not at all. Popups that hinder the user doing what he wants to do (he wants to leave the site when he clicks the link) are undesirable. This is extremely bad UI design.

Comment: It is a work for school. I am not saying that it is a good thing, but i cant argue with what they want us to do. But thank for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery dialog would be perfect for this just add code

```
warning.onclick = function()
{
 var msg = "do you want to leave this site: ";

 $( "#dialog-confirm" ).html(msg);
 $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
resizable: false,
title: 'title',
height:300,
modal: true,
buttons: {
    "Ok": function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        window.location.href = url;
        },
    "Cancel": function() {
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
    });
   }
```

Answer (score -1):

do this instead:

```
var boolOK = confirm('Do you want to leave');

if (boolOK == true)
warning.onclick;
```

more explanations here
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/alert2.shtml

Comment: Never compare boolean variables against `true`!